# Create an std::vector from a formatted file

Tags: c++, file, vector

I ran into this bit of code:

```
ifstream file ("data.in");
std::vector<int> v;
file >> v;
```

Which works, for a file that looks like this:

```
3
1 2 3
```

And the vector will contain the elements 1, 2 and 3. How exactly does this work, or why? I didn't use std::vector a lot so far (mainly cause the only time I used C++ at college was in Data Structures class and we had to write our own versions of the structures), but at a first glance it doesn't look like this should work.

Are there any more "tricks" like this one?

Comment: Someone, somewhere, had overloaded `operator>>` for `std::istream` and `std::vector`. You've posted an incomplete code...

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Didn't even think of checking the header file, I got way too excited by this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works by overloading the `>>` operator for `ifstream` and `vector`. It probably looks something like this:

```
template <typename Char, typename Traits, typename T>
std::basic_istream<Char, Traits>& operator>>(std::basic_istream<Char, Traits>& is, std::vector<T>& v)
{
    std::size_t s;
    if (!(is >> s))
        return is;
    v.resize(s);
    for (auto& i : v)
    {
        is >> i;
    }
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Just as @LogicStuff said in his comment. You are indeed right, I didn't check the header file before posting.